# jquery data() not working

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

I'm having some trouble with the jquery data function.

$(e.target).data("unitId") comes as undefined.

I've been trying to troubleshoot this for a while but can't find what is wrong with my code.

Does anyone see what's wrong here?

```
var SomeView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#sidebar',
    events: {
        "click .link-unit": "route"
    },
    initialize: function(){

        this.render();

    },
    render: function(){
        this.$el.html('<div class="link-unit" data-unitId="some data">some text</div>');
    },
    route: function(e){
        console.log($(e.target).data('unitId'));
    },
});
```

Comment: when do you call `$(e.target).data("unitId") `??

Comment: Can you provide the relevant markup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you request `.data("dataId")` with camelcase, jQuery turns that into a request for the attribute `"data-data-id"`.

You can fix it by not using camelcase.  For example, if you use all lowercase for the attribute name in both the HTML and in your jQuery, it all works just fine.  Or, you can change the HTML to use `"data-data-id"` for the attribute name and keep the camelcase in the HTML.

This explanation is from [the jQuery doc](https://api.jquery.com/data/):

> `<div data-role="page" data-last-value="43" data-hidden="true" data-options='{"name":"John"}'></div>`
>
> `$( "div" ).data( "lastValue" ) === 43;`
>
> The ... above code correctly refers to the
>   `data-last-value` attribute of the element. In case no data is stored
>   with the passed key, jQuery searches among the attributes of the
>   element, converting a camel-cased string into a dashed string and then
>   prepending data- to the result. So, the string `lastValue` is converted
>   to `data-last-value`.

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/uaoL0hdn/

Answer (score 0):

Instead try:

```
$(e.target).data("unitid")
```

Always try to use all lowercase in your markup and code so you do not run into such issues.

> For example, given the following HTML:
>
> ```
>  <div data-role="page" data-last-value="43" data-hidden="true" data-options='{"name":"John"}'></div>
> ```
>
> All of the following jQuery code will work.
>
> ```
> $( "div" ).data( "role" ) === "page";
> $( "div" ).data( "lastValue" ) === 43;
> $( "div" ).data( "hidden" ) === true;
> $( "div" ).data( "options" ).name === "John";
> ```
>
> The second statement of the code above correctly refers to the
>   `data-last-value` attribute of the element. In case no data is stored
>   with the passed key, jQuery searches among the attributes of the
>   element, **converting a camel-cased string into a dashed string and then
>   prepending data- to the result**. So, **the string lastValue is converted
>   to `data-last-value`**.

Ref: https://api.jquery.com/data/

Comment: `data` is case-sensitive

Comment: thanks, it works indeed.
I'm surprised as in the JQuery data() documentation they give example which contain upper cases